# Delphi: Log the GET request URLs used in Websites that are updating content via AJAX (TWebbrowser)

Tags: ajax, delphi, twebbrowser, get-request

Using a TWebBrowser in Delphi, I'm showing a website that uses JSON to update its content. To get the source code of the newly updated content and load it into a Memo, I believe I have to get the URLs of the GET requests. Unfortunately, these are always different and generated with an encrypted Javascript. Is there any way to list the URLs the GET requests go to in a similar way like FireBug does in its console view?

Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: You can't really "encrypt" a URL. Browsers don't decrypt URLs, so whatever URL the browser is asked to fetch must already be the real URL. You're probably trying to solve your problem at the wrong level. Since you want to get the updated content of the page's HTML, why bother reading URLs at all? Just ask the browser control to tell you its current contents. If you try to learn the URLs and fetch their contents yourself, you're still stuck with the task of interpreting the Javascript so that you can apply the same page transformations the browser already did when *it* loaded the JSON.

Comment: @RobKennedy Thanks for the quick response! That would be the easiest solution. Unfortunately, if I try and get the source code of the webpage after the new content has been loaded, it still shows the old source code of when the page was first loaded. Any thoughts on how to get the real "current" contents?

Comment: I suppose you could get what you need from the DOM, since that's all the JavaScript is probably manipulating anyway. Any information beyond that is just something I'd get from researching the documentation and Google, and you can do that yourself.

Comment: usually JS do AJAX in MSIE via a special XMLHttpRequest object. I dunno if MSIE DOME would allow you t osubstitute your custom object instead, that would additionally do the URL logging. Another option - somewhat fragile i think - would be implementing HTTP proxy in your application, enforce embedded MSIE to route the traffic through it and catch the URLs en passant. Extra hard to do if SSL/TLS would be used.